# Sci-Fi book where main character gets modified by a genius scientist and can hear prerecorded messages chemically implanted inside his brain

Tags: story-identification, books

Maybe you guys can help me remember the title of a book I read over 30 years ago back in middle school in the early 1980s.

It was a science fiction book. I don't remember any character names. Just a cloudy recollection of the events. The main character for some reason gets modified (willingly or not?) by a genius scientist who then dies (I think) but the main character can hear prerecorded messages chemically (maybe??) implanted inside his brain explaining his new powers and why he was given them.

Something to do with a portal to another dimension that is paradise except for some malevolent super entity that the main character was modded to fight against.

Comment: Reminiscent of Keith Laumer plots but not specific enough to say which one.